# SQL performance problem: Select N rows until find distinct 200 customer

Tags: sql-server

I have table ORDERS with these columns:

id    |   Customer   |   product

I want to calculate **N** number of rows in ORDERS table. **N** should be big enough to contain 200 distinct CUSTOMER from bottom of table. I have wrote the following query using max(ID) but It takes too many seconds to run this query. I think this is not optimized because I have thousands of rows and every time I have to use `group by` on whole table to find just an ID:

```
select count(*) as N from ORDERS where id > (
 select top 1 id from 
      (select distinct top 200 CUSTOMER,max(id) as maxid from ORDERS group by CUSTOMER order by maxid desc) x
 order by id asc
)
```

Is there another way to handle this with better performance?

Comment: " better performance" - than what?"but It takes too many seconds to run this query"  - how do you know it's too many?

Comment: Does that query even return anything? The clause with the sub query will, effectively, evaluate to `WHERE id > id`, which can never be true. Something can never be greater than itself. (`id` within the subquery will be the value of `id` in the outer query, as that part of the subquery (returning data from `x`) doesn't have a column `id` (the columns are `CUSTOMER` and `maxid`). A column, without an alias, will always default to the inner query, unless that column doesn't exist in that query, then it'll look "outside").

Comment: I have about 150K rows and this query takes about 10 seconds to run. I have no idea what can cause this unexpected delay?@MitchWheat

Comment: Unfortunately you are true and it always returns 0 after a long time @Larnu

Comment: @AliSheikhpour yep, as i said, `id > id` will always evaluate to false.

Comment: Why are you asking about performance when the query doesn't even return the correct result? First fix your query to return the correct data, then you can think about performance. Performance tuning of an incorrect query is nonsensical.

Comment: Never truer words have been said @HoneyBadger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a huge guess, but this will at least return a result:

```
WITH Customers AS(
    SELECT TOP 200
           CUSTOMER,
           MAX(id) AS MaxID
    FROM ORDERS
    GROUP BY CUSTOMER
    ORDER BY MaxID DESC)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ORDERS O
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Customers C
              WHERE C.MaxID = O.id);
```

If it returns the **correct** results, but it still runs slowly, post the DDL of your table, and **include** the DDL for your indexes. I also suggest posting the query plan by using [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: I get SQL syntax error. Sorry I am not familiar with this syntax and I can not guess where the problem comes from?

Comment: Without knowing the error, how can I answer, @AliSheikhpour?

Comment: Looking at my query (I haven't tested it mind, as there's no sample data), I can't see any syntax errors.

Comment: I got this error but I solved it: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.` I had to separate it from previous queries using `GO`

Comment: @AliSheikhpour the correct thing to do would have been to terminate your statements, like the error tells you...